# When should one use final for method parameters and local variables?

Tags: java, final

I've found a couple of references ([for example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23)) that suggest using `final` as much as possible and I'm wondering how important that is. This is mainly in the the context of method parameters and local variables, not final methods or classes. For constants, it makes obvious sense.

On one hand, the compiler can make some optimizations and it makes the programmer's intent clearer. On the other hand, it adds verbosity and the optimizations may be trivial.

Is it something I should make an effort to remember?

Comment: Here is a related post to look over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java

Comment: I'm upvoting just because I didn't know that it was possible to use final as a modifier on parameters before reading this.  Thanks!

Comment: Later question, but just the same [why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java?)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Obsess over:

- Final fields - Marking fields as final forces them to be set by end of construction, making that field reference immutable.  This allows safe publication of fields and can avoid the need for synchronization on later reads.  (Note that for an object reference, only the field reference is immutable - things that object reference refers to can still change and that affects the immutability.)
- Final static fields - Although I use enums now for many of the cases where I used to use static final fields.

Consider but use judiciously:

- Final classes - Framework/API design is the only case where I consider it.
- Final methods - Basically same as final classes.  If you're using template method patterns like crazy and marking stuff final, you're probably relying too much on inheritance and not enough on delegation.

Ignore unless feeling anal:

- Method parameters and local variables - I RARELY do this largely because I'm lazy and I find it clutters the code.  I will fully admit that marking parameters and local variables that I'm not going to modify is "righter".  I wish it was the default.  But it isn't and I find the code more difficult to understand with finals all over.  If I'm in someone else's code, I'm not going to pull them out but if I'm writing new code I won't put them in.  One exception is the case where you have to mark something final so you can access it from within an anonymous inner class.
- Edit: note that one use case where final local variables are actually very useful as mentioned by [@adam-gent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856192/2750743) is when value gets assigned to the var in the `if`/`else` branches.

Comment: Joshua Bloch argues that all classes should be defined as final, unless they are designed for inheritance. I agree with him; I add final to every class that implement an interface (to be able to create unit tests). Also mark as final all protected/class methods, which are not going to be overridden.

Comment: With all due respect to Josh Bloch (and that's a considerable amount), I disagree for the general case.  In the case of building an API, sure lock things down.  Bui inside your own code, erecting walls that you later have to tear down is a waste of time.

Comment: It's definitely not a "waste of time", specially because it costs no time at all... In an application, I normally make almost all classes `final` by default. You may not notice the benefits unless you use a truly modern Java IDE, though (ie, IDEA).

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. What benefits do you get in IntelliJ?

Comment: IDEA has (out of the box) hundreds of code inspections, and some of those can detect unused/unnecessary code in `final` classes/methods. For example, if a final method declares to throw a checked exception but never actually throws it, IDEA will tell you that, and you can remove the exception from the `throws` clause. Sometimes, you can also find whole methods that are unused, which is detectable when they can't be overriden.

Comment: Eclipse has some of the same inspections (probably NetBeans too).  I'll grant you this as a benefit but I'm not convinced it's a big deal.

Comment: Java should have just made final the default!! uggg!

Comment: I'd like to have a Java editor that "changes" the default for method parameters and local variables: It should hide the final keyword in declarations, and highlight declarations without final. Unfortunately, I don't think that such an editor exists. There is a [request for this feature in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409379).

Comment: @rmaruszewski Marking classes as final prevents most mocking frameworks from being able to mock them thus making you code harder to test. I would only make a class final if it was critically important  that it is not extended.

Comment: The "Unnecessary 'final' on local variable or parameter" inspection in IDEA is a game changer.
Then call "More actions..." on the reported final keyword and select "Cleanup code" and finals are vanished.

Comment: Let's also don't forget that Java compiler has such thing as "efficiently final" variables - compiler optimization will auto mark such fields as final under the hood.

Answer (score 48):

> Is it something I should make an effort to remember to do?

No, if you are using Eclipse, because you can configure a Save Action to automatically add these *final* modifiers for you. Then you get the benefits for less effort.

Comment: Great tip with the Save Action, didn't know about that.

Comment: I'm mainly considering the benefit that *final* makes the code safer from bugs by accidentally assigning to the wrong variable, rather than any optimisations that may or may not happen.

Comment: Is this really a problem for you?  How often have you actually had a bug that resulted from this?

Comment: +1 for useful tip in Eclipse. I think we should use final as much as possible to avoid bugs.

Comment: Can you do this in IntelliJ as well?

Comment: Yes, intellij has a plugin for it, here is the link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions

Answer (score 17):

The development-time benefits of "final" are at least as significant as the run-time benefits.  It tells future editors of the code something about your intentions.

Marking a class "final" indicates that you've not made an effort during design or implementation of the class to handle extension gracefully.  If the readers can make changes to the class, and want to remove the "final" modifier, they can do so at their own risk.  It's up to them to make sure the class will handle extension well.

Marking a variable "final" (and assigning it in the constructor) is useful with dependency injection.  It indicates the "collaborator" nature of the variable.

Marking a method "final" is useful in abstract classes.  It clearly delineates where the extension points are.

Answer (score 17):

I use `final` all the time to make Java more expression based. See Java's conditions (`if,else,switch`) are not expression based which I have always hated especially if your used to functional programming (ie ML, Scala or Lisp).

Thus you should try to always (IMHO) use final variables when using conditions.

Let me give you an example:

```
    final String name;
    switch(pluginType) {
        case CANDIDATE_EXPORT:
            name = "Candidate Stuff";
            break;
        case JOB_POSTING_IMPORT:
            name = "Blah";
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

Now If add another `case` statement and do not set `name` the compiler will fail. The compiler will also fail if you do not break on every case (that you set the variable). This allows you to make Java very similar to Lisp's `let` expressions and makes it so your code is not massively indented (because of lexical scoping variables).

And as @Recurse noted (but apparently -1 me) you can do the preceding with out making `String name` `final` to get the compiler error (which I never said you couldn't) but you could easily make the compiler error go away setting name after the switch statement which throws away the expression semantics or worse forgetting to `break` which you cannot cause an error (despite what @Recurse says)  without using `final`:

```
    String name;
    switch(pluginType) {
        case CANDIDATE_EXPORT:
            name = "Candidate Stuff";
            //break; whoops forgot break.. 
            //this will cause a compile error for final ;P @Recurse
        case JOB_POSTING_IMPORT:
            name = "Blah";
            break;
    }
    // code, code, code
    // Below is not possible with final
    name = "Whoops bug";
```

Because of the bug setting name (besides forgetting to `break` which also another bug) I can now accidentally do this:

```
    String name;
    switch(pluginType) {
        case CANDIDATE_EXPORT:
            name = "Candidate Stuff";
            break;
        //should have handled all the cases for pluginType
    }
    // code, code, code
    // Below is not possible with final
    name = "Whoops bug";
```

The final variable forces a single evaluation of what name should be. Similar to how a function that has a return value must always return a value (ignoring exceptions) the name switch block will have to resolve name and thus bound to that switch block which makes refactoring chunks of code easier (ie Eclipe refactor: extract method).

The above in OCaml:

```
type plugin = CandidateExport | JobPostingImport

let p = CandidateExport

let name = match p with
    | CandidateExport -> "Candidate Stuff"
    | JobPostingImport -> "Blah" ;;
```

The `match ... with ...` evaluates like a function ie expression. Notice how it looks like our switch statement.

Here is an example in Scheme (Racket or Chicken):

```
(define name 
    (match b
      ['CandidateExport "Candidate Stuff"]
      ['JobPostingImport "Blah"]))
```

Comment: Except that the java compiler will already give you an "name potentially uninitialised" error and refuse to compile with or without the final.

Comment: Yes but with out the final you could reset it at anytime. I have actually seen this happen where a developer turned an `else if (...)` into a `if(...)` and thus resetting the variable. I showed him that would never have happened with a final variable. Basically `final` forces you to assign the variable once and only once... so :P

Comment: Do you understand that you are in Java devs minority, right?)

Answer (score 10):

Well, this all depends on your style... if you LIKE seeing the final when you won't be modifying the variable, then use it.  If you DON'T LIKE seeing it... then leave it out.

I personally like as little verbosity as possible, so I tend to avoid using extra keywords that aren't really necessary.

I prefer dynamic languages though, so it's probably no surprise I like to avoid verbosity.

So, I would say just pick the direction you are leaning towards and just go with it (whatever the case, try to be consistent).

---

As a side note, I have worked on projects that both use and don't use such a pattern, and I have seen no difference in the amount of bugs or errors... I don't think it is a pattern that will hugely improve your bug count or anything, but again it is style, and if you like expressing the intent that you won't modify it, then go ahead and use it.

Comment: Style bender over here)

Answer (score 9):

I've found marking method parameters and locals as `final` is useful as a refactoring aid when the method in question is an incomprehensible mess several pages long.  Sprinkle `final` liberally, see what "cannot assign to final variable" errors the compiler (or your IDE) throws up, and you just might discover why the variable called "data" ends up null even though several (out of date) comments swear that can't happen.

Then you can fix some of the errors by replacing the reused variables with new variables declared closer to the point of use.  Then you find you can wrap whole parts of the method in scoping braces, and suddenly you're one IDE keypress away from "Extract Method" and your monster just got more comprehensible.

If your method is *not* already an unmaintainable wreck, I guess there might be value in making stuff final to discourage people from turning it into said wreck; but if it's a short method (see: not unmaintainable) then you risk adding a lot of verbosity.  In particular, Java function signatures are hard enough to fit into 80 characters as it is without adding six more per argument!

Comment: Very valid last point, although I gave up on the 80 characters limit long time ago as screen resolution has changed a bit in the last 10 years. I can easily fit a 300 char line on my screen without scrolling. Nevertheless, readability is of course better without the `final` before every parameter.

Answer (score 7):

It is useful in parameters to avoid change the parameter value by accident and introduce a subtle bug. I use to ignore this recommendation but after spending some 4 hrs. in a horrible method ( with hundreds of lines of code and multiple fors, nested ifs and all sort of bad practices ) I would recommend you to do it.

```
 public int processSomethingCritical( final int x, final int y ){
 // hundreds of lines here 
     // for loop here...
         int x2 = 0;
        x++; // bug aarrgg...
 // hundreds of lines there
 // if( x == 0 ) { ...

 }
```

Of course in a perfect world this wouldn't happen, but.. well.. sometimes you have to support others code. :(

Comment: This method has more serious issues than missing final. It's pretty uncommon, although not impossible, that there's a good reason for a method to be so cluttered that these sorts of errors would occur. A little thought put into variable names would go a long way toward accidents like this.

Comment: If you have "hundreds of lines of code" in a single method you may want to break it out into several smaller methods.

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing a application that someone will have to read the code after, say, 1 year, then yes, use final on variable that should not be modified all the time. By doing this, your code will be more "self-documenting" and you also reduce the chance for other developers to do silly things like using a local constant as a local temporary variable.

If you're writing some throwaway code, then, nah, don't bother to identify all the constant and make them final.

Answer (score 4):

I will use final as much as I can. Doing so will flag if you unintentionally change the field. I also set Method parameters to final. Doing so I have caught several bug from code I have taken over when they try to 'set' a parameter forgetting Java passes by value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the question whether this is obvious, but making a method parameter final affects only the body of the method. It does **NOT** convey any interesting information about the method's intentions to the invoker. The object being passed in can still be mutated within the method (finals are not consts), and the scope of the variable is within the method.

To answer your precise question, I wouldn't bother making an instance or local variable (including method parameters) final unless the code required it (e.g. the variable is referenced from an inner class), or to clarify some really complicated logic.

For instance variables, I would make them final if they are logically constants.

Answer (score 2):

There are many uses for the variable `final`. Here are just a few

**Final Constants**

```
 public static class CircleToolsBetter {
     public final static double PI = 3.141;
        public double getCircleArea(final double radius) {
          return (Math.pow(radius, 2) * PI);
        }
    }
```

This can be used then for other parts of your codes, or accessed by other classes, that way if you would ever change the value you wouldn't have to change them one by one.

**Final Variables**

```
public static String someMethod(final String environmentKey) {
    final String key = "env." + environmentKey;
    System.out.println("Key is: " + key);
    return (System.getProperty(key));

  }

}
```

In this class, you build a scoped final variable that adds a prefix to the parameter environmentKey. In this case, the final variable is final only within the execution scope, which is different at each execution of the method. Each time the method is entered, the final is reconstructed. As soon as it is constructed, it cannot be changed during the scope of the method execution. This allows you to fix a variable in a method for the duration of the method. see below:

```
public class FinalVariables {


  public final static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Note how the key variable is changed.");
    someMethod("JAVA_HOME");
    someMethod("ANT_HOME");
  }
}
```

**Final Constants**

```
public double equation2Better(final double inputValue) {
    final double K = 1.414;
    final double X = 45.0;

double result = (((Math.pow(inputValue, 3.0d) * K) + X) * M);
double powInputValue = 0;         
if (result > 360) {
  powInputValue = X * Math.sin(result); 
} else {
  inputValue = K * Math.sin(result);   // <= Compiler error   
}
```

These are especially useful when you have really long lines of codes, and it will generate compiler error so you don't run in to logic/business error when someone accidentally changes variables that shouldn't be changed.

**Final Collections**

Different case when we are talking about Collections, you need to set them as an unmodifiable.

```
 public final static Set VALID_COLORS; 
    static {
      Set temp = new HashSet( );
      temp.add(Color.red);
      temp.add(Color.orange);
      temp.add(Color.yellow);
      temp.add(Color.green);
      temp.add(Color.blue);
      temp.add(Color.decode("#4B0082")); // indigo
      temp.add(Color.decode("#8A2BE2")); // violet
      VALID_COLORS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(temp);
    }
```

otherwise, if you don't set it as unmodifiable:

```
Set colors = Rainbow.VALID_COLORS;
colors.add(Color.black); // <= logic error but allowed by compiler
```

**Final Classes** and **Final Methods** cannot be extended or overwritten respectively.

**EDIT:TO ADDRESS THE FINAL CLASS PROBLEM REGARDING ENCAPSULATION:**

There are two ways to make a class final. The first is to use the keyword final in the class declaration:

```
public final class SomeClass {
  //  . . . Class contents
}
```

The second way to make a class final is to declare all of its constructors as private:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public final static SOME_INSTANCE = new SomeClass(5);
  private SomeClass(final int value) {
  }
```

Marking it final saves you the trouble if finding out that it is actual a final, to demonstrate look at  this Test class. looks public at first glance.

```
public class Test{
  private Test(Class beanClass, Class stopClass, int flags)
    throws Exception{
    //  . . . snip . . . 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, since the only constructor of the class is private, it is impossible to extend this class. In the case of the Test class, there is no reason that the class should be final. The Test class is a good example of how implicit final classes can cause problems.

**So you should mark it final when you implicitly make a class final by making it's constructor private.**

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of a trade-off as you mention, but I prefer explicit use of something over implicit use.  This will help remove some ambiguity for future maintainers of code - even if it is just you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have inner (anonymous) classes, and the method needs to access variable of the containing method, you need to have that variable as final.

Other than that, what you've said is right.

Comment: Now java 8 offers flexibility with effective final variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use `final` keyword for a variable if you are making that variable as `immutable`

By declaring the variable as final, it aids developers to rule out possible modification issues of variables in highly multi-threaded environment.

With java 8 release, we have one more concept called "***`effectively final variable`***". *A non-final variable can heave as final variable.*

***local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final***

> A variable is considered ***effective final*** if it is not modified after initialization in the local block. This means you can now use the local variable without final keyword inside an anonymous class or lambda expression, provided they must be effectively final.

***Till Java 7, you cannot use a non-final local variable inside an anonymous class, but from Java 8 you can***

Have a look at this [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/03/what-is-effectively-final-variable-of.html)

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the final keyword is used to make a variable constant. Constant means it does not change. For example:

```
final int CM_PER_INCH = 2.54;
```

You would declare the variable final because a centimeter per inch does not change.

If you try to override a final value, the variable is what it was declared first. For example:

```
final String helloworld = "Hello World";
helloworld = "A String"; //helloworld still equals "Hello World"
```

There is a compile error that is something like:

```
local variable is accessed from inner class, must be declared final
```

If your variable cannot be declared final or if you don't want to declare it final try this:

```
final String[] helloworld = new String[1];
helloworld[0] = "Hello World!";
System.out.println(helloworld[0]);
helloworld[0] = "A String";
System.out.println(helloworld[0]);
```

This will print:

```
Hello World!
A String
```