# Final fields and Immutable Classes

Tags: java, private, immutability, final

According to this: [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

One of the conditions for a class to be immutable, is making all its fields final and private.

Why final??? The other conditions aren't sufficient?

Comment: Read carefully: _Not all classes documented as "immutable" follow these rules._

Comment: `final` has implications for thread-safety - see this blog post: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.nz/2008/04/immutability-in-java.html

Comment: Can `Class.getDeclaredField().set...` be used to change the value of a final field? I know it can be used to change the value of a private field.

Answer (score 1):

Without making the field `final` we can make an immutable class/object if other conditions are available.

But I think the `final` is useful while dealing with concurrency and synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Per the definition for an immutable object (courtesy of Wikipedia) "In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created."

Once an final object has been created it cannot be re-assigned.  Without the final key work you could still change an object after it has been created.

See also
[final object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271287/)

Comment: If the class is final and its fields are private and no setters are defined and we don't share references to the mutable objects (via getters for example), the class is immutable...these conditions are sufficient (no need for the fields to be final).

Comment: Why not let the compiler check that for you?

Comment: I appear to be having some difficulty with the enter key tonight
There are different levels of immutable which may or may not use final, I will not even pretend like I understand them all.  

An example of why the other conditions alone are not sufficient “in certain cases” from Oracles documentation:
“final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization.”
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5-110

For a probably much better answer then my own see assylias response in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061030/

Answer (score 1):

Counter question "Why not final?".

`final` means for primitive types you'll not be able to change the value once assigned which is enough to make them Immmutable,

while for non-primitive types the reference can't be changed (1st step towards Immutability) once assigned and you need to do some more as mentioned in the link shared by you.

Comment: but the other conditions are sufficient.

Comment: Because you are writing an immutable class and you are sure that once assigned its never going to change hence take the benefits potential runtime optimizations and compile time inlining

Answer (score 0):

The key to the linked document is this quote

> Not all classes documented as "immutable" follow these rules....However, such strategies require sophisticated analysis and are not for beginners.

This is a tutorial for beginners.  It's easier to tell them "make everything private and final" then have to explain all the edge cases with how to properly handle mutable references and making sure not to let your references escape.