# GridData class in SWT

Tags: swt, grid-layout

This is about GridData class in SWT UI programming. Why should GridData be final ?

Java Doc of GridData says that it's final. I want to understand why it should be final.

Thank and Regards

Answer (score 2):

Frankly there is no reason not to be final, It's common behavior of API programmers to make all classes which are not determined to be extended.

Read [When should one use final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154314/when-should-one-use-final) and [Using “final” modifier whenever applicable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java) stackoverflow questions for more info. It also relates with [SWT subclassing FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#subclassing).

Comment: Yes,I know when final has to be used.But my doubt here why GridData should be like that...

Comment: You ask wrong question, the question is why should it not be final..?

Answer (score 0):

Sorceror is correct. From an API point-of-view, you always want to make everything final to prevent future extensions of the API because somebody have been creative in their sub-classing...

In this particular example the reason is likely to be that the designer though he might need additional members in the class in some future. E.g. there are `minimumHeight` and `minimumWidth` in the current version, but no `maximumHeight` and `maximumWidth` which could make sense as well... But what if you or somebody else had extended `GridData` with private members with these exact names? Then the API extension would not be forward compatible and a lot of code could potentially break this way.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for your explaination ..  Could you suggest me what can I do , to become good at Object Oriented Design ..

Comment: If you miss something in Layout manager, you use bad one. Try another layout managers, like MigLayout, I'm sure you will not miss there anything..