# Using try/catch to declare and initialize a final variable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to declare and initialize a final variable in an adapter in order to use the variable in an `OnLongClickListener()` declaration. The problem is that the variable is being initialized by a method that can potentially throw a failure exception, so the initialization must happen in the context of a try/catch. In the exception block, there is a fallback value that the final variable is assigned to instead. This all happens within the overridden `getView()` of the `ArrayAdapter<T>`.

My question is, is there a slick way to do this? I've gotten around this by just declaring a temporary variable outside the try/catch, and initializing it in the try/catch, then declaring and initializing the final variable after the try/catch block with the results of the temporary variable. This just feels too messy.

[This question is pretty closely related, but the solution presented seems extreme. Is it typical to wrap the entire contents of a method in a try/catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350605/java-how-to-declare-final-a-variable-that-is-initialized-inside-a-try-catch-b)

Code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Data.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//begin eww gross
        Vehicle temp;
        try {
            temp = Data.getVehicle(values.get(position).getId());
        } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + "-- unable to find vehicle while getting list item vehicle for vehicles tab fragment");
            temp = values.get(position);
        }
        final Vehicle vehicle = temp;
//end disappointing, ugly workaround

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_item_with_img, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.vehicleLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_label);
            holder.statusImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lmImageView);
            holder.sImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sImageView);
            holder.vehicleTag = vehicle.getId();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (Data.isFollowingVehicle(vehicle)) {
            holder.sImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.sImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        holder.statusImage.setImageDrawable(vehicle.getListIcon());
        holder.vehicleLabel.setText(vehicle.getFormattedLabel());

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (!vehicle.isFollowed()) {
                    finalHolder.sImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mapInterface.follow(vehicle);
                } else {
                    finalHolder.sImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mapInterface.unfollow(vehicle);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mapInterface.handleVehicleClickFromList(vehicle);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you can use field instead, are you?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/field.html

Comment: @gio I guess I'm not familiar enough with the reflection properties of field to know how to use them to get around this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to move the logic to get the Vehicle into its own method. It makes it reusable and easier to read.

```
private Vehicle getVehicle(int position) {
    try {
        return Data.getVehicle(values.get(position).getId());
    } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + "-- unable to find vehicle while getting list item vehicle for vehicles tab fragment");
        return values.get(position);
    }
}
```

and then back in your original method:

```
final Vehicle vehicle = getVehicle(position);
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will wait a little bit longer for more answers before accepting, but I like this one a lot.