# Blank final with Reference type

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap, final

why we can change a hashMap which is declared as blank final, but we cannot change a primitive type?
for example 
if I create a map

```
final Map<String, String> someMap;
```

and initialize it in constructor, and still I can put values in this. But same is not the case with primitive

```
final int a;
```

I cant change the value of a in this case. can somebody explain this ?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154314/when-should-one-use-final

Comment: Are you saying you can't change 'a' in the constructor? Because that should be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` means it cannot be changed once initialized. You are just declaring the variable but not initializing it, hence it is allowed.

So doing this is valid

```
final Map<String, String> someMap;
someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

But if you try to assign another value to it post initialization then compiler should throw an error that final variable is already intialized:

```
    final Map<String, String> someMap;
    someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    someMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(); //error here
```

**Note:** Also putting/removing values in hashmap does not change the reference of the final variable.

Comment: but same is not allowed in the case of primitives ?

Comment: primitives are data types that hold the value, while references are like pointers, which do not hold their values but point to their values and are used on/with objects. If you understand this part, then you will understand also why you can do put on a final hashMap reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the reference to the map (i.e. the variable `someMap`) which cannot be changed. The map itself can be changed. You can for example insert values. But you cannot assign a new map to `someMap`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the final keyword on variables you are saying that the variable can be defined only once. In other words once a value has been assigned to the variable, it cannot be reassigned.

This yields obvious behavior with primitive types but is less obvious with objects. Importantly though when inserting values into a map, the object instance remains the same. This is important to remember when passing objects to methods, and really important when using get/set/clone methods as you may end up with multiple references to the same object, where a change in one place (insert entry into map) may have undefined effects in others.

If the Map in your question is important you can use `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);` to stop people fiddling with it.

Answer (score 1):

*`emphasized text`*When you write:

```
final Map<String, String> someMap;
```

it's important to realise that `someMap` is a *reference*, and you're declaring the reference to be final. The actual object is not immutable, but the reference is. Hence you can't change the reference i.e. you can't do:

```
someMap = anotherMap;
```

later on.