# What are the benefits to marking a field as `readonly` in C#?

Tags: c#, readonly, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

What are the benefits of having a member variable declared as read only?  Is it just protecting against someone changing its value during the lifecycle of the class or does using this keyword result in any speed or efficiency improvements?

Comment: Good external answer: http://www.dotnetperls.com/readonly

Comment: Interesting. This is essentially the C# equivalent of this Java question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java

Discussion here is much less heated though...

hmm...

Comment: It may be worth noting that `readonly` fields of structure types impose a performance penalty compared with mutable fields that are simply not mutated, since the invocation of any member of a `readonly` value-type field will cause the compiler to make a copy of the field and invoke the member on that.

Comment: more on the performance penalty: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword is used to declare a member variable a constant, but allows the value to be calculated at runtime.  This differs from a constant declared with the `const` modifier, which must have its value set at compile time.  Using `readonly` you can set the value of the field either in the declaration, or in the constructor of the object that the field is a member of.

Also use it if you don't want to have to recompile external DLLs that reference the constant (since it gets replaced at compile time).

Comment: but how about the benefits of speed and efficiency? are there any?

Comment: It pays to bare in mind that if you assign readonly to something like a class such as `private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> _ready = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();` then you can still use `_ready.SetResult(true)` so the readonly applies only to the field and not necessarily the object's properties or state. Const is also not just as simple as "compile time" - it can't be used for all the same things like readonly can... const can only hold strings, ints bools or null. For example you can't do `const HttpClient hello5 = new HttpClient();` but you can for `readonly`

Comment: @NotoriousPyro the reason you can't do `const HttpClient hello5 = new HttpClient()` is precisely because a new HttpClient is allocated at runtime. It really is as simple as "compile-time". Even structs are allocated at runtime and cannot be const.

Answer (score 223):

I don't believe there are any performance gains from using a readonly field.  It's simply a check to ensure that once the object is fully constructed, that field cannot be pointed to a new value.

However "readonly" is very different from other types of read-only semantics because it's enforced at runtime by the CLR.  The readonly keyword compiles down to .initonly which is verifiable by the CLR.

The real advantage of this keyword is to generate immutable data structures.  Immutable data structures by definition cannot be changed once constructed.  This makes it very easy to reason about the behavior of a structure at runtime.  For instance, there is no danger of passing an immutable structure to another random portion of code.  They can't changed it ever so you can program reliably against that structure.

Robert Pickering has written a good blog post about the benefits of immutability. The post can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-know-immutable-data-st) or at the [archive.org backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20190910111734/http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2008/05/18/1617.aspx).

Comment: If you read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860595/prevent-changing-the-value-of-string-empty read only member can be modified and looks like an inconsistent behavioir by .net

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/

“Make struct ‘X’ readonly” analysis - The best way to avoid subtle bugs and negative performance implications with structs is to make them readonly if possible. Readonly modifier on a struct declaration clearly expresses a design intend (emphasizing that the struct is immutable) and helps the compiler to avoid defensive copies in many contexts mentioned above.

Answer (score 82):

There are no apparent performance benefits to using `readonly`, at least none that I've ever seen mentioned anywhere. It's just for doing exactly as you suggest, for preventing modification once it has been initialised.

So it's beneficial in that it helps you write more robust, more readable code. The real benefit of things like this come when you're working in a team or for maintenance. Declaring something as `readonly` is akin to putting a contract for that variable's usage in the code. Think of it as adding documentation in the same way as other keywords like `internal` or `private`, you're saying "this variable should not be modified after initialisation", and moreover you're *enforcing* it.

So if you create a class and mark some member variables `readonly` by design, then you prevent yourself or another team member making a mistake later on when they're expanding upon or modifying your class. In my opinion, that's a benefit worth having (at the small expense of extra language complexity as doofledorfer mentions in the comments).

Comment: And otoh desimplifies the language. Not denying your benefit statement, however.

Comment: I agree, but I suppose the real benefit comes when more than one person is working on the code. It's like having a small design statement within the code, a contract for its usage. I should probably put that in the answer, hehe.

Comment: This answer and discussion is actually the best answer in my opinion +1

Comment: @Xiaofu: You made me constant of the idea of readonly hahaha beautiful explanation that nobody in this world could explain the silliest mind an understand

Comment: Ie you are staying intent in your code that this value should not change at any time.

Answer (score 66):

To put it in very practical terms:

If you use a const in dll A and dll B references that const, the value of that const will be compiled into dll B. If you redeploy dll A with a new value for that const, dll B will still be using the original value.

If you use a readonly in dll A and dll B references that readonly, that readonly will always be looked up at runtime. This means if you redeploy dll A with a new value for that readonly, dll B will use that new value.

Comment: This is a good practical example to understand the difference. Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, `const` may have performance gain over `readonly`. Here is a bit deeper explanation with code : https://www.dotnetperls.com/readonly

Comment: I think the biggest practical term is missing from this answer: the ability to store values computed at runtime into `readonly` fields. You can’t store a `new object();` in a `const` and that makes sense because you can’t bake non-value things such as references into other assemblies during compile time without changing identity.

Answer (score 22):

There is a potential case where the compiler can make a performance optimization based on the presence of the readonly keyword.

This only applies if the read-only field is also marked as *static*. In that case, the JIT compiler can assume that this static field will never change. The JIT compiler can take this into account when compiling the methods of the class.

A typical example: your class could have a static read-only *IsDebugLoggingEnabled* field that is initialized in the constructor (e.g. based on a configuration file). Once the actual methods are JIT-compiled, the compiler may omit whole parts of the code when debug logging is not enabled.

I have not checked if this optimization is actually implemented in the current version of the JIT compiler, so this is just speculation.

Comment: is there a source for this?

Comment: The current JIT compiler in fact does implement this, and has since CLR 3.5. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1079

Comment: No optimizations can be done on readonly fields for the simple reason that readonly fields are not readonly but readwrite. They are just a compiler hint that most compilers respect and the values of readonly fields can easily be overwritten through reflection (although not in partially trusted code).

Answer (score 11):

Keep in mind that readonly only applies to the value itself, so if you're using a reference type readonly only protects the reference from being change. The state of the instance is not protected by readonly.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, readonly can actually result in slower code, as Jon Skeet found when testing his Noda Time library. In this case, a test that ran in 20 seconds took only 4 seconds after removing readonly.

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/

Comment: Note that if the field is of a type which is a `readonly struct` in C# 7.2, the benefit of making the field non-readonly goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget there is a workaround to get the `readonly` fields set outside of any constructors using `out` params.

A little messy but:

```
private readonly int _someNumber;
private readonly string _someText;

public MyClass(int someNumber) : this(data, null)
{ }

public MyClass(int someNumber, string someText)
{
    Initialise(out _someNumber, someNumber, out _someText, someText);
}

private void Initialise(out int _someNumber, int someNumber, out string _someText, string someText)
{
    //some logic
}
```

Further discussion here: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2013/01/23/Setting-Readonly-Fields-From-Chained-Constructors.aspx

Comment: The fields are still assigned in the constructor.. there is no "getting around" that. It doesn't matter if the values are from single expressions, from a decomposed complex type, or assigned via call by reference semantics of `out` ..

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Adding a basic aspect to answer this question:*

Properties can be expressed as readonly by leaving out the `set` operator. So in most cases you will not need to add the `readonly` keyword to properties:

```
public int Foo { get; }  // a readonly property
```

In contrast to that: Fields need the `readonly` keyword to achieve a similar effect:

```
public readonly int Foo; // a readonly field
```

So, one benefit of marking a field as `readonly` can be to achieve a similar write protection level as a property without `set` operator - without having to change the field to a property, if for any reason,  that is desired.

Comment: Is there a difference in behavior between the 2?

Comment: @petrosmm yes, you can set the readonly field using reflection, you cannot using the property

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with private readonly arrays. If these are exposed a client as an object (you might do this for COM interop as I did) the client can manipulate array values. Use the Clone() method when returning an array as an object.

Comment: No; expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: This should be a comment not a answer as it provides no answer to the question...

Comment: Funnily enough, I got told to put this sort of thing as an answer, rather than a comment when I did it on another post last week.

Comment: As of 2013, you can use `ImmutableArray<T>`, which avoids boxing to an interface (`IReadOnlyList<T>`) or wrapping in a class (`ReadOnlyCollection`). It has performance comparable to native arrays: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/06/24/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting part of usage of readonly marking can be protecting field from initialization in singleton.

for example in code from [csharpindepth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

readonly plays small role of protecting field Singleton from being initialized twice. Another detail is that for mentioned scenario you can't use const because const forces creation during compile time, but singleton makes creation at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pre defined or pre calculated value that needs to remain same through out the program then you should use constant but if you have a value that needs to be provided at the runtime but once assigned should remain same throughout the program u should use readonly. for example if you have to assign the program start time or you have to store a user provided value at the object initialization and you have to restrict it from further changes you should use readonly.

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` can be initialized at declaration or get its value from the constructor only. Unlike `const` it has to be initialized and declare at the same time.
`readonly` *has everything* `const` *has, plus constructor initialization*

**code** https://repl.it/HvRU/1

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine(new Test().c);
        Console.WriteLine(new Test("Constructor").c);
        Console.WriteLine(new Test().ChangeC()); //Error A readonly field 
        // `MainClass.Test.c' cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a 
        // variable initializer)
    }


    public class Test {
        public readonly string c = "Hello World";
        public Test() {

        }

        public Test(string val) {
          c = val;
        }

        public string ChangeC() {
            c = "Method";
            return c ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be a performance benefit in WPF, as it removes the need for expensive DependencyProperties. This can be especially useful with collections

Comment: `DependecyProperty` is used for a very different purpose than a field

Comment: Agreed, and together they are in the same ecosystem of monitoring mutations. If you can gaurentee that a field does not change, then you don't need to monitor it's mutations, hence the performance benefit