# Resharper changing fields to readonly

Tags: c#, resharper, readonly

I am trying out Resharper and i notice that it is recommending to set instance level fields to readonly. For example:

```
private readonly IConnection _connection;

public RetrieveCommand(IConnection connection) {
    _connection = connection;
}
```

What is the benefit of marking fields like this readonly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It recommends that you should set it to `readonly` because the only place you assign the `_connection` member is in the constructor.  That is the only place you are allowed to assign to a readonly member.

See this article for an explanation: [Developer Corner: Mark C# class data member as readonly when it's read only](http://www.developer-corner.com/2009/01/mark-c-class-data-member-as-readonly.html)

Answer (score 8):

[What are the benefits to marking a field as `readonly` in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c)