# Is a readonly field in C# thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, readonly

Is a `readonly` field in C# thread safe?

```
public class Foo
{
  private readonly int _someField;

  public Foo()
  {
    _someField = 0;
  }

  public Foo(int someField)
  {
    _someField = someField;
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     doSomething(_someField);
  }
}
```

Have gone through some posts:

- [What are the benefits to marking a field as readonly in C#? - JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277117/219516) suggests that readonly fields once constructed are immutable and hence safe.
- [Readonly Fields and Thread Safety](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/readonly-fields-and-thread-safety/), suggests that there is some risk if constructors do a lot of work.

So, if the `readonly` field is used as in the code above, and constructors are light, is it thread-safe? What if `_someField` is a referrence type (e.g. an array of strings)?

Comment: It doesn't depend on whether the ctor does a "lot" of work or not, it depends on whether the ctor lets the instance escape and after that goes back and changes the readonly field again.

Comment: only the reference is readonly the collection isn't. So if you'd put a list in a readonly field. adding and removing from the list will not be thread safe.

Comment: @the_ajp Which collection?  I can't see any collections in his posted code.

Comment: @BenRobinson there isn't any but in the last line of his question he hints at what happens with an array of strings and because I knew this about collections I thought it might be relevant to add the comment.

Comment: @harold, thanks for correcting. Yes, the thought was about not letting the instance escape.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes - your code doesn't expose `this` within either constructor, so no other code can "see" the object before it's been fully constructed. The .NET memory model (as of .NET 2) includes a write barrier at the end of every constructor (IIRC - search Joe Duffy's blog posts for more details) so there's no risk of another thread seeing a "stale" value, as far as I'm aware.

I'd personally still usually use a property instead, as a way of separating implementation from API, but from a thread-safety point of view it's fine.

Comment: Isn't GUID one exception as it is 128 bits? with 64 bit word length it would take 2 cache updates, please correct me.

Comment: @RohitSharma: I don't think so - I believe it's guaranteed to be fully visible before the constructor completes and the reference becomes visible to the calling code.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but, I thought for value types the semantics are: it's completely constructed in a separate buffer and then copied all at once to wherever it was assigned to. That copy does not sound very atomic to me..

Comment: @harold: It doesn't need to be atomic if it's not visible to anything else *before* it gets there, *then* there's a write barrier, and then it won't change - so anything reading outside will always see the same value.

Comment: Yes, but it could be visible already (for example a readonly GUID field in a struct instead of in a class). And then it's not thread safe, right?

Comment: @harold: In that case I think it's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4):

That depends what's in the field.

Reading from a readonly field, or from any field that is smaller than the word length (including all reference types) is an atomic operation.

However, the object inside the readonly field may or may not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at your example but in general it depends what is readonly applied to, for example if dictionary is declared readonly you can still update keyvalue pairs