# Is readonly variable thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a readonly field in C# thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286222/is-a-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-thread-safe)

A quite simple program

```
private readonly string _data1;
private readonly int _data2;
private readonly MyAnotherClass _data3;

public MyClass(string data1, int data2, MyAnotherClass data3)
{
    _data1 = data1;
    _data2 = data2;
    _data3 = data3;
}
```

Are `_data1,  _data2 and _data3` thread safe?

Comment: How can you call a constructor from several threads?

Comment: [Jon Skeet has your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286222/is-a-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-thread-safe)

Comment: @zerkms, you tell me if I can do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A read-only variable is guaranteed to be initialized before it is accessed.  The initial value is assigned during construction of the object, before the object is fully allocated.

> Variable initializers are transformed into assignment statements, and these assignment statements are executed before the invocation of the base class instance constructor. This ordering ensures that **all instance fields are initialized by their variable initializers before any statements that have access to that instance are executed**.

Reference: C# Spec, 10.11.3 Constructor execution (emphasis mine)

> Assignment to a readonly field can only occur as part of the field’s declaration or in a constructor in the same class

Reference: C# Spec, 1.6.5 Fields

For that reason, the value will be set before it is available to any thread, and will not change, so it is thread safe.

Comment: I'm asking about a constructor. In general, are the variables in a constructor thread safe?

Comment: Yes, they are thread safe.  The object is not returned by the compiler and available for access by any thread until the given object instance is fully constructed.  Added a reference to the C# spec to clarify that point.

Comment: Well, a static constructor is absolutely thread safe since it's called only one time in App Domain. Is this true for an instance constructor as well?

Comment: @Alexandre: Yes, it is.  Try to imagine code that can access a field or property of a class before the reference becomes available in your program.  In other words, given `MyClass my = new MyClass();`, how would you possibly access fields or properties of `my` before the instance is actually assigned from `new MyClass()`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are because no software can change them once the class is constructed.

**EDIT**

While the data fields are thread safe, the contents of _data3 are not thread safe.  Differents threads could modify _data3 "simultaneously".

Comment: Could a constructor be called more than one thread at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but you would be constructing a different object; so no thread safety issues.

Comment: +1. especially on thread safety of `_data3`.

Comment: <<the contents of _data3 are not thread safe>> Please explain. Can they modify it in constructor?

Comment: @Alexandre, anyone can modify _data3.SomeField anywhere.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, does it mean that _data3 = new MyAnotherClass is impossible but _data3.SomeField = 123 is possible? Do you mean exactly the reference to _data3 and it can't be changed, right?

Answer (score 1):

Joh Skeets' answer at [Is a readonly field in C# thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286222/is-a-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-thread-safe) gives most of the answer - for immutable types (like `int`/`string`) it is threadsafe.

In case of custom type that is not immutable reference itself will be thread safe, but `readonly` does not guarantee anything about content of the object. So all properties of `_data3` object need to have custom thread safety protection.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't later change them, yes they are.

Edit:

```
class Class1
{

    readonly string bigbuddy;

    public Class1()
    {

        bigbuddy = "1";

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(SomeThread);
        thread1.Start(this);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        bigbuddy = "2";

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(SomeThread);
        thread2.Start(this);

    }

    public void SomeThread(object state) {

        Class1 class1 = (Class1)state;

        Debug.WriteLine(class1.bigbuddy);

    }


}
```

Use:

```
 Class1 asd = new Class1();
```

Output:

```
1
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe0c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
2
The thread '<No Name>' (0x129c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Show me how to change the value of a read-only variable after construction... (OK might be possible with reflection I guess, but that defeats the point of readonly).

Comment: -1 because a `readonly` cannot be changed later.

Comment: @BernaMariano: No need to be rude.

Comment: A `readonly` can be changed later using reflection.

Comment: Please see my added example, still threadsafe?

Comment: Not so damn vocal now huh???!

Comment: But no other thread can modify the variable.  So it is thread safe.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: Wrong. The constructor is running in a thread, it can modify the variable. It is not thread safe.