# Can modulo division be optimised if the base is fixed?

Tags: c#, optimization

Given the following expression in C#, and that `chunkWidth` and `chunkHeight` are fixed pre-calculated numbers, is it possible to optimise the expression by perhaps pre-computing part of the modulo division beforehand?

```
// Once assigned these guys never change
private int _chunkWidth;
private int _chunkHeight;

// This function needs to be super optimal!
SomeObject LookupObject(int row, int column) {
    int index = (row % _chunkHeight) * _chunkWidth + (column % _chunkWidth);
    return _objects[ index ];
}
```

Comment: If they never change why aren't they defined as constants?? This MAY provide some optimization. Now in general terms I do not see any other thing you can do to optimize this...

Comment: @Spiritios they cannot be constants because they get calculated when the data structure is generated.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a case of the XY problem(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Are you totally sure that the problem lies in optimizing this rather than in the larger picture? :)

Comment: @Spiritios possibly, I have a chunked data structure (which has gaps where there is no data). To access an individual item my code first looks up the chunk (`SomeObject`) and then looks up the item in that chunk. So there are in total 3 `%`'s to access a single item. And item access is extremely frequent and is causing some noticeable slowdown as it's often called thousands of times per frame.

Comment: I would look to classes and method calls as a possible bottleneck before I looked at modulos and multiplications.

Comment: @Kiyura Do you mean perhaps create a hybrid function which inlines the second accessor resulting in one method call instead of two?

Comment: Speaking of which, does the .NET compiler (or JIT) perform inlines on functions in C#?

Comment: No, I meant that I would see if I could store the data in a struct or an array and access it directly in a loop rather than branching. Classes and method calls in C# have noticeable overhead if we're talking about realtime graphics. (In fact, I probably wouldn't have chosen C# for this.)

Comment: @Kiyura Well I have two choices really. There are four data fields per item. I can either store those in a class or store them as 4 parallel arrays. Due to a technical limitation with the platform that I am using I cannot use structs (which I would prefer if it were possible). Would 4 parallel array lookups be better than looking up and using class instances?

Comment: Yes. And if you want to make it extra simple for the runtime to optimize, try to access the arrays linearly (if you just looked up 43, look up 44 next).

Comment: Thanks @Kiyura I will spend some time experimenting with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `chunkWidth` and `chunkHeight` are fixed and pre-calculated fields, but still you cannot further optimize the modulo operation since `row` and `column` are variables which requires modulo operation each time the statement is executed.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I saw that `%` was the same as `A - B * (A / B)` so I wasn't sure if perhaps part could be recalculated. My initial thoughts were to pre-calculate `1 / B` and then just multiply when I soon realised that would be impossible given that I am working with integer division.

Answer (score 3):

To allow the variables to only be assigned once, you can add the `readonly` attribute to them. This may allow some optimizations. I wouldn't be terribly worried about the performance of basic arithmetic operations, though, not unless this has proven to be an *extremely* tight bottleneck.

Comment: I might be able to reorganise the class a little so that they can be assigned using the constructor and thus be marked as `readonly`. At the moment the class is created earlier and initialised when it is first accessed.

Comment: This is new for me, can you share some reference regarding performance boost with the help of readonly fields? Since i thought this is only possible with const field.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar, that's a good question. I had assumed it would aid performance optimizations, but apparently it does not: http://www.dotnetperls.com/readonly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c  So really, the only reason you should use readonly is to improve the clarity of your code (which is still an excellent reason).