# How to get value set by other class

Tags: c#

I am new at C#
Let's say I have 4 Classes:

Holder:

```
public class Holder
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

SecondClass:

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public void SecondClassMethod()
    {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.Name = "John";
        Console.WriteLine(holder.Name + " from SecondClass");
    }
}
```

AnotherClass:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public void AnotherClassMethod()
    {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.Name = "Raphael";
        Console.WriteLine(holder.Name + " from AnotherClass");
    }

}
```

and final Program class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Holder x1 = new Holder();
        SecondClass x2 = new SecondClass();
        AnotherClass x3 = new AnotherClass();

        x1.Name = "Nobody";
        Console.WriteLine(x1.Name);
        x2.SecondClassMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(x1.Name);
        x3.AnotherClassMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(x1.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
}
```

Output after running program:

```
Nobody
John from SecondClass
Nobody
Raphael from AnotherClass
Nobody
```

My Question is:
How I can get proper name (given by that other classes) using Program class ? Thing is I want to use that set,get on Holder class. I can't figure it out.

I want to get:

```
Nobody
John from SecondClass
John
Raphael from AnotherClass
Raphael
```

as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're instantiating a [new instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) of `Holder` in each class. In order to modify the existing instance, you need to [pass a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx) to the other classes.

You can do that by [introducing a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx), where you store a reference to the `Holder` instance in a [private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) (preferably [readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c)) [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class SecondClass
{
    private readonly Holder _holder;
    public SecondClass(Holder holder)
    {
        _holder = holder;
    }

    public void SecondClassMethod()
    {
        _holder.Name = "John";
        Console.WriteLine(_holder.Name + " from SecondClass");
    }
}
```

Then change the code using that class:

```
Holder x1 = new Holder();
SecondClass x2 = new SecondClass(x1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use a [public property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) in your classes to store the reference of the `Holder` instance that you want to modify:

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public Holder Holder { get; set; }

    public SecondClass(){}

    public void SecondClassMethod()
    {
        if (Holder!=null)
        {
            Holder.Name = "John";
            Console.WriteLine(Holder.Name + " from SecondClass");
        } 
    }
}
```

And then in `Main` method you could do this:

```
Holder x1 = new Holder();
SecondClass x2 = new SecondClass(){Holder=x1};
x2.SecondClassMethod();
```