# How to make a const array of string with enum as keys?

Tags: c#, enums

Here's what I'd like to do in CSharp but I dont know how to do this (*I know this is not valid `C#`*):

```
const enum GameOver { Winner, Looser, Tied, };
GameOvers = [
    GameOver.Winner: "Person is the winner",
    GameOver.Looser: "Person is the looser",
    GameOver.Tied: "Game is tied",
]
```

And later on, I want to be able to call it like:

```
Display(GameOvers[GameOver.Winner])
```

(I want to handle a const array of errors like this actually).

How would you do in `C#`?

Comment: You could use the Description attribute or [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424366/1070452) ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer

Comment: This question could have what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest approach that comes into my mind is using a `Dictionary<GameOver, string>`:

```
enum GameOver { Winner, Loser, Tied };

Dictionary<GameOver, string> GameOvers =  new Dictionary<GameOver, string>()
{
    {GameOver.Winner, "Person is the winner"}, 
    {GameOver.Loser,  "Person is the loser"},
    {GameOver.Tied,   "Game is tied"}
};
```

But notice, that you can't make the `Dictionary` really constant, since the instance is mutable.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I've done just before you answered **`;^)`** Thanks a lot, and have a nice day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static readonly String[] Messages =
{
    "Person is the winner",
    "Person is the looser",
    "Game is tied"
};

public enum GameOver
{
    Winner = 0,
    Looser = 1,
    Tied = 2
}

Display(Messages[(Int32)GameOver.Winner]);
```

Maybe less compact, but functional. Your strings will also be insured to be immutable thanks to the `readonly` attribute ([What are the benefits to marking a field as `readonly` in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c)).

Comment: Strings are always immutable. The array, however, is not. The readonly keyword only makes the variable ``Messages`` read-only, not the array it points to.

Comment: I problably explained it in a wrong way but the concept behind the code looks kinda clear.