# How do I pass an instance of a class when creating a new class?

Tags: c#

Here is what I would like to do:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel(this);

    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{

    PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame;

    PhrasesFrameViewModel(PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame) {
        this.phrasesFrame = phrasesFrame;
    }
```

I want to give the new PhrasesFrameViewModel a reference to the class that created it.

However I get the message:

> Keyword "this" is not available in the current context

Comment: Create the view model in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the view model in the constructor in order to have access to `this` keyword in the correct context.

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame {
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm;

    public PhrasesFrame() {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel(this);
    }

    //...
}
```

This assumes that the view model has a publicly accessible constructor that accepts the passed argument.

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty {

    private readonly PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame;

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel(PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame) {
        this.phrasesFrame = phrasesFrame;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an error saying 'PhrasesFrameViewModel.PhrasesFrameViewModel(PhrasesFrame)' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Comment: @Alan2 does the view model have a publicly accessible constructor that accepts the passed argument?

Comment: I added the view model class code to the question now. I think you are correct.  It was not public. When I made it public then it seemed to work. Can you tell me, is this the correct coding for the view model?

Comment: @Alan2 standard practice if there is no intention to change the field after initialization/assignment. If you have intentions of changing the field then so not make it read-only. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c