# Wrong usage of exception - return value from catch

Tags: java, exception

This is the piece of code.

```
  private boolean CheckTerm()
      {
          String str = lGskCompoundNumber;
          if (lPrefix.trim() == "" || lNumber.trim() == "")
              return false;

          try
          {
              Integer.parseInt(lNumber);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              return false;
          }
          if (lHasAmpersand)
              str = lGskCompoundNumber.replace("&", "");
          return str.equals(lPrefix + lInitSep + lNumber + lEndSep + lSuffix);
      }
```

Should I return a certain value from catch block or is the usage right?

Comment: What do you mean by "Should I return a certain value from catch block ", return to where?

Comment: I think he's asking if you should use the `return` keyword in a `catch` block. I think that's fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code is correct and does not look suspicious. When parsing fails (note that you should catch the most narrow exception possible, `NumberFormatException` in this case), whole validation failed, so you are returning `false`. Otherwise you are performing additional checks (after `catch` block) and returning their result. This code is fine.

If you find it a bit hard to read, consider the following refactoring:

```
private boolean checkTerm() {
    try
        {
            String str = lGskCompoundNumber;
            if (lPrefix.trim() == "" || lNumber.trim() == "")
                return false;
            Integer.parseInt(lNumber);
            if (lHasAmpersand)
                str = lGskCompoundNumber.replace("&", "");
            return str.equals(lPrefix + lInitSep + lNumber + lEndSep + lSuffix);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong in your code but I always prefer to have a single exit point in my methods, so I prefer to write something like:

```
private boolean CheckTerm()
{
    boolean res = false;
    String str = lGskCompoundNumber;
    if (lPrefix.trim() == "" || lNumber.trim() == "")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(lNumber);
            if (lHasAmpersand)
                str = lGskCompoundNumber.replace("&", "");
            res = str.equals(lPrefix + lInitSep + lNumber + lEndSep + lSuffix);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is okay if you know what you want to return. 
If I could give a hint on the number of exits(returns) you use.
I would use a boolean field and just return once after the try / catch Block

```
private boolean CheckTerm()
{
  boolean b = true;
  String str = lGskCompoundNumber;
      if (lPrefix.trim() == "" || lNumber.trim() == "")
          b = false;

      try
      {
          Integer.parseInt(lNumber);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          b =  false;
      }
      if (lHasAmpersand)
          str = lGskCompoundNumber.replace("&", "");
      b = str.equals(lPrefix + lInitSep + lNumber + lEndSep + lSuffix);
      return b;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return some value in catch block, and even in finally block.

It's totally okay.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the conditions of `CheckTerm` is that `lNumber` should be an integer, then your code is ok, but if you're expecting `lNumber` to be an integer and it's not, you'll better throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Its fine as is though I would catch the exception differently.

That method your calling throws a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

it seems as though just returning false would be fine, i would do some sort of logging to keep track of the exception though [discussion on how to handle your exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410107/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-a-numberformatexception-when-it-is-expected)

Answer (score 1):

if you afraid there is no default returns, using finally, then return something.

```
try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(lNumber);
        if (lHasAmpersand)
            str = lGskCompoundNumber.replace("&", "");
        res = str.equals(lPrefix + lInitSep + lNumber + lEndSep + lSuffix);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
       return false;
    }finally{return false;}
```