# InvocationTargetException - Call Rest service from java Soap webservice using httpClient

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I am created soap webservice in my server. And I want to call other service(In another server) from my soap service using httpClient with "POST" method. I used "httpclient-4.2.2.jar" and "httpcore-4.2.2.jar".

Code snippet:

```
    public class User {
        public static String addUser(String userEmail, String password) {
            final String uri = "http://www.example.com/";
            String requestParams = String.format("{\"userEmail\": \"%s\", \"password\": \"%s\"}", userEmail, password);

            final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
            postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestParams, "utf-8"));

            try {
               final HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
               final String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "utf-8");
               System.out.println(responseData);
            } catch(final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return responseData;
        }
    }
```

When I call this menthod from another class using the following code.

```
    User.addUser(userEmail, password);
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.DefaultSubjectValve.invoke(DefaultSubjectValve.java:56)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:406)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ThreadCleanerValve.invoke(ThreadCleanerValve.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.access$200(JarFileClassLoader.java:52)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader$6.run(JarFileClassLoader.java:308)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.findClass(JarFileClassLoader.java:260)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.MultiParentClassLoader.loadOptimizedClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:441)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:281)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:448)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:309)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:286)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.test.User.addUser(User.java:18)
    ... 34 more
```

It throws the "InvocationTargetException". What may be the problem? Can you give your suggestions?

Comment: Post the stacktrace - in which line does the exception occur?

Comment: It throws exception in the line "User.addUser(userEmail, password)".

Comment: Post the stacktrace... An InvocationTargetException is wrapping an exception thrown within a dynamic invocation, so likely there will be a "Caused by..." somewhere in the trace showing the real issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added my stacktrace in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right there in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
```

and if you look closer at the lines below, you can see an indication of where it goes wrong (hint: `DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:157)`)

To cut to the chase: Loose the `final` modifiers on `uri`, `client`, `postMethod`, `response` and `responseData`. They're unnecessary and/or wrongly used anyway.

On a completely other note, you *could* add `final` modifiers to the methods formal arguments `userEmail` and `password`, but do [read up on `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java) first.

Cheers,