# Do I overuse final here?

Tags: java, final

I have read a lot about `final` and when to use it or not ,and I have come to the conclusion that it's mostly personal design. So, consider this class below, is this a case where I'm overusing final or not? I know that I should write readable and clear code ,and I think this still is pretty clear consider all the final.

```
public final class ConsoleUtil {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Bukkit.getLogger();

private ConsoleUtil() {

}

public static void info(final Object... objects) {
    log(Level.INFO, objects);
}

public static void warning(final Object... objects) {
    log(Level.WARNING, objects);
}

public static void severe(final Object... objects) {
    log(Level.SEVERE, objects);
}

public static void exception(final Exception e, final Object... objects) {
    warning(objects);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private static void log(final Level level, final Object... objects) {
    for (Object object : objects) {
        LOGGER.log(level, "[HubControl] " + object.toString());
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: if wherever you've used _final_ the intention is that _this object reference should never be reassgined_ then it's fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "final" modifier whenever applicable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java)

Comment: There can never be too many `final` variables.

Comment: You forgot one: `for (final Object obect: objects`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion that the choice is mostly personal is mostly correct, so you should not really be asking the question, because the answer is off topic as  "primarily opinion-based".

I will try to give you an answer which is as far from opinion-based as possible.

Finality is a most excellent quality for any data item, and any opportunity to make something `final` should be pursued tenaciously.  On the other hand, with java, it becomes extremely tedious to add `final` to every single little thing that can be made final. This also becomes kind of futile given that the compiler analyzes your code and can figure out whether a variable is *effectively final* when finality actually matters.

So, the approach taken by most java developers is to refrain from using final all over the place.  Note that this is not subjective, it is a report of the state of the industry.

We could ask the gurus at Oracle to add finality-by-default to the language, so that everything is final unless declared otherwise, or we could use a different language where finality-by-default is already built in.